# Changing double precision raster file using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table

I am using ArcMap 10.2.

I’m trying to create an attribute table for an NDVI tif file. The pixel type of my file is double precision, so I tried first multiplying the whole thing by 10^n, however I have 16 decimal places. For some reason when I use the INT tool afterwards it just gives me one category (which is 0). I can try multiplying by 10^9, and then I have no problem using the INT tool, but I feel like I’m losing resolution by using only 9 places.

Is there any other method to change from double precision into signed integer?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. please specify the software that you are using in order to attract meaningful answer. By the way, 9 decimal places for NDVI is more than enough: it is useless to store information with more decimal places than its true precision (3 or 4 decimal places would be fine) and some software have limited entry values for raster attribute tables

Comment: Multiply it by 1000. Period. Everything after 3rd decimal in NDVI is computer garbage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ArcGIS, *[it is not possible to build a raster attribute table for a raster dataset that is a pixel type of 32-bit floating point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-raster-attribute-table.htm)*, therefore the best option is to change the pixel type of your data by using [Copy Raster tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm). Before that, however, you have to clarify how to transform your NDVI to a desired range, which is also called stretching or normalization. As you know the raw NDVI values range between -1.0 and +1.0, usually this range is transformed to a 0-100 scale or better 0-255 (8 unsigned integer range). I think the latter option will be sufficient to process specifically the NDVI as its best, since it is an index and 0-255 range helps to differentiate vegetation from the others. The transformation or re-scaling is explained in various places, such as [this ESRI support page](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008671).

.